# Multiple Tex files result in blank bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have read multiple entries on this site for my issue but still cannot make the connection.  I have `main.tex`, `Frontmatter.tex`, `chapter1.tex`  and want to `\input{Frontmatter.tex}` and then have `main.tex` print the bibliography for all files to end the document.  All files share the same bibliography (`library.bib`)  How to I get citations from all files to write into one bibliography at the end of the document?  main file included here:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[right=1in,left=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addto\captionsamerican{%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {\centering{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}%
}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\title{}
\begin{document}
\input{FrontMatter.tex}
\input{chapter1.tex}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the problem?  That should work assuming you are `\cite`-ing entries from `library.bib` in your `\input`-ed files, and then running `latex main.tex`, `biber main.bcf`, `latex main.tex`.  If you are getting an error message on any of those three commands, please add them to your question.

Comment: Continuing on @jon 's comment: Try adding `\nocite{*}` just before `\printbibliography`, and then process by `latex`, `biber`, `latex`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had \end{document} in the bottom of each chapter.  It never made it to the \printbibliography command.  Thank you for the posting tip, it looked gnarly when I first posted.